# Ajuda com Pilha em PHP

Tags: php

Estou com uma dúvida em um tipo de estrutura em PHP. Mais precisamente em um exercício.

Escreva um programa para que dadas três pilhas P1, P2 e P3.

A pilha P1 possui n números inteiros quaisquer. As pilhas P2 e P3 estão vazias. Deseja-se passar todos os números pares da pilha P1 para a pilha P2. A pilha P3, se necessário, poderá ser utilizada como uma pilha auxiliar. Ao final P1 terá os números ímpares, P2 os números pares e P3 vazia.

Não posso usar função pronta como array_reserve por exemplo e afins. 
Tentei fazer assim, mas está dando erro. Alguém saberia por quê?

```
<?php

class Pilha {

    private $lista;
    public $valor = 20;
    public $topo = -1;

    public function empilha($valor)
    {
        $this->lista[] = $valor;
        $this->topo++;
    }

    public function remove()
    {
        $this->topo--;
    }

    public function __isset($lista)
    {
        if ($this->topo < 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function getTopo()
    {
        return $this->lista[$this->topo];
    }

}

$p1 = new Pilha();
$p2 = new Pilha();
$p3 = new Pilha();
while (!$p1 . __isset($lista)) {
    if ($p1 . getTopo() % 2 == 0) {
        $p3 . empilha($p1 . getTopo);
    }
    $p1 . remove();
}

while (!$p3 . __isset($lista)) {
    $p2 . empilha($p3 . getTopo);
    $p3 . remove();
}
```

Comment: Precisa estar ordenada cada pilha?

Answer (score 1):

Para acessar os métodos você deve utilizar o flecha '->' e não o ponto '.'.
Outra coisa é o método `__isset` ele é um método de para overloading da chamada do isset para essa classe, ou seja quando eu chamar `isset($classe)` ele vai executar o `__isset` da sua classe ao invés do padrão. ([mais infos aqui](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.isset))

Então tomei a liberdade de renomear seu método para `_isset` (com apenas um underscore '_')
Ficando assim:

```
<?php
class Pilha {

    private $lista = [];
    private $topo = -1;

    public function empilha($valor) {
        $this->topo++;
        $this->lista[$this->topo] = $valor;
    }

    public function remove() {
        if($this->_isset())
            unset($this->lista[$this->topo]);
            $this->topo--;
    } 

    public function _isset() {
        $ret = true;

        if($this->topo < 0) {
            $ret = false;
        }

        return $ret;
    }

    public function getTopo(){
        return $this->lista[$this->topo];
    }
}

//lista principal
$p1 = new Pilha();
//lista de pares
$p2 = new Pilha();
//lista tmp
$p3 = new Pilha();

//preenche pilha de ex. 1,2,3...100
for($i = 1; $i < 101; $i++) {
    $p1->empilha($i);
}

//move pilha
while($p1->_isset()) {
    $topo = $p1->getTopo();

    if($topo % 2 == 0) {
        $p2->empilha($topo);
    }
    else {
        $p3->empilha($topo);
    }

    $p1->remove();
}

//agora p1 esta vazia, p2 esta com os pares e p3 com os impares
//soh jogar o p3 para o p1 ($p1 = $p3) ou fazer um loop (como eh pra facu possivemente o professor vai querer assim)
while($p3->_isset()) {
    $p1->empilha($p3->getTopo());
    $p3->remove();
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($p1, $p2, $p3);
```

Comment: eu manteria o método mágico `__isset` e mudaria as chamada no while para `isset($p1)`

Comment: o remover não deveria retornar o o topo?

Comment: Desnecessária a classe `Pilha`. No php já temos um cara chamado `SplStack` e `SplDoubleLinkedList`.

Comment: Se você ler a pergunta é um exercício, ou seja, ele esta (estava) aprendendo os conceitos de pilha.

Answer (score 0):

**Primeira versão**

```
$arr[1] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; // Pilha 1
$arr[2] = $arr[1]; // Pilha 2

/*
Remove os números ímpares da pilha 1
*/
foreach($arr[1] as $k => $v) if($v%2==0) unset($arr[1][$k]);

/*
Remove os números paresda pilha 2
*/
foreach($arr[2] as $k => $v) if($v%2!=0) unset($arr[2][$k]);

/*
Imprime os resultados (finalidade de testes)
*/
print_r($arr[1]);

/*
Necessário verificar se a pilha 2 existe e não está vazia.
*/
if (isset($arr[2]) && !empty($arr[2]))
    print_r($arr[2]);
```

1. O exercício não fala sobre uso de classes ou orientação a objeto.
2. O exercício não obriga o uso da "pilha 3".
3. O exercício não especifica que não é permitido "clonar" todos os dados da pilha 1 para a pilha 2.
4. O resultado retorna o que se pede.

**Segunda versão, otimizada**

```
/*
Pilha 1
*/
$arr[1] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$arr[2] = [];

foreach( $arr[1] as $k => $v )
{
    if($v%2==0)
    {
        /*
        Atribui os valores pares a pilha 2
        */
        $arr[2][] = $v;
        /*
        Remove os valores pares da pilha 1
        */
        unset($arr[1][$k]);
    }
}

/*
Imprime os resultados (finalidade de testes)
*/
print_r($arr[1]);

/*
Necessário verificar se a pilha 2 existe e não está vazia.
*/
if (isset($arr[2]) && !empty($arr[2]))
    print_r($arr[2]);
```

Nessa segunda versão, a segunda pílha recebe somente os valores ímpares. ao contrário da primeira versão onde a segunda pilha recebe todos os dados da pilha 1 para então seguir com os procedimentos de filtragem.

Comment: Isso não é pilha, isso é array normal.